# In which format i have to send my formData to PHP Backend?

Tags: php, axios, form-data

In my Vue Component i use axios.post to send Data to my PHP Backend

```
 const formData = new FormData()
 const form_data = JSON.stringify( this.form_fields ).toString()
 formData.append( 'form_data', form_data )
 axios.post( url, formData )
        .then(response => 
        console.log(response))
```

The Data in my form_data looks like:

```
 [{"title": "any title", "content":"any content"}, {"title": "any title", "content":"any content"}]
```

In PHP the string looks like

```
  [{\"title\": \"any title\", \"content\":\"any content\"}, {\"title\": \"any title\", \"content\":\"any content\"}]
```

i remove the \" with str_replace and afterwards i seralize the string to save in my backend.

Unfortunately, if my text include line breaks, the content cannot be saved.

How do i send the data to php without lose anything? also html formatted information not saved to my database.

How the string has to look like?

Comment: try removing the `JSON.stringify` stuff and use `axios.post( url, this.form_fields )`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
const formData = new FormData()
const form_data = JSON.stringify( this.form_fields ).toString()
formData.append( 'form_data', form_data )
```

Rather, do this:

```
var form = $("#formId")[0]; //Select your form with, say, id='formId'
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

To get the `POSTed` values in PHP you could loop through the `POST` array, or get them individually. For example:

```
$something = $_POST['formElementName']; //formElementName is the name attribute of the element in your form
```

Comment: thank pieter, but in vue it's easier to catch the values with data attribute. my question is about formatting the string and not to to catch the data, that already work.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string looks just fine and does not have to change. Keep in mind that HTML line breaks `<br/>` do not get converted to `\n` in this step.

The problem is on the PHP side where you replace the `\` with string str_replace which will probably also mess up the new line `\n` characters.

Try a proper deserialisation of the JSON string in php:

```php
$decoded = json_decode($jsonString);
```

Try to get the values from the `$decoded` array. (They should be ok, also with line breaks.)

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I had a function in php which translate the json into serialize string.

Answer (score 0):

I had a function which manage the string

```
 function get_serialized_string( $data ) {
     $post = str_replace( '\"', '"', $data );
     $post = str_replace('<p><br></p>', '', $post );
     $post = str_replace( '\n', '"', $post );
    return serialize( json_decode( ( $post ) ) );
 }
```

but i have still the problem with saving the content.

if my textarea include a link which has a formatted color in e.g rgba(0,0,0, 2.5), than it will return null.

my axios data in header

```
 [{\"name\":\"Stanley\",\"email\":\"stan@stan.de\",\"description\":\"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span style=\\\"color: rgb(230, 0, 0);\\\">consetetur sadipscing elitr,</span> sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et&nbsp;</p><p><br></p>\",\"website\":\"https://test.de\"}]
```

how do i translate the string that .i looks like:

```
 a:1:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:4:"name";s:7:"Stanley";s:5:"email";s:12:"stan@stan.de";s:11:"description";s:83:"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore</p>";s:7:"website";s:15:"https://test.de";}}
```

it will works if i not format the text color

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have additional questions or want to ellaborate more about what is not working edit your existing question. Also you say: Problem with saving the content. What did you try? How does the data look like? Do you get an error message? Be specific.

Comment: the data look like  [{\"name\":\"Stanley\",\"email\":\"stan@stan.de\",\"description\":\"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span style=\\\"color: rgb(230, 0, 0);\\\">consetetur sadipscing elitr,</span> sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et&nbsp;</p><p><br></p>\",\"website\":\"https://test.de\"}] and i want to generate a serialized string